# With selenium, Is it possible to identify a dynamic web element selector that has a specific pattern?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to find a web element by a CSS selector, but the Selectors change each time the page is loaded and adhere to a certain pattern:

The selector is always 10 characters long

The 2nd character is always an integer between 1-9

the 7th character is always a capital letter

The 10th character is always a lowercase letter between a-g

e.g.

a8DFf3Ac3e

z1Az5fE52b

Is it possible to tell selenium webdriver that the element appeared if it sees a CSS selector that matches this pattern?

I am using selenium webdriver with Python

Comment: What are those? `class`es, `id`s, or something else?

Comment: They are ids  id=

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a CSS selector alone, but a JS script would be sufficient:

```js
elements = driver.execute_script(
  '''
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')]
    .filter(element => element.id.match(/^.[1-9]....[A-Z].[a-g]$/))
  '''
)
```

The snippet above selects every element that has an `id` which matches the regex `^.[1-9]....[A-Z].[a-g]$`, JavaScript way. You can, of course, do the same in Python with `By.CSS_SELECTOR`:

```py
elements_with_id = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id]')
elements_with_matching_id = [
  element for element in elements_with_id
  if re.fullmatch(r'.[1-9]....[A-Z].[a-g]', element.get_attribute('id'))
]
```

They work (mostly) the same. Your choice.